MAUI - how to bind VisualElement property to a variable in a View
I want to bind my RowDefinition Height to a variable in the code behind of my View class.
The problem is that I have defined the BindingContext of my MainPage to a MainPageViewModel and now I need to bind it to MainPage again. I was trying to use self-bind but it is not created for such problems or I don't know how to use it correctly.
The code that I have tried:
<Grid.RowDefinitions BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MainPage}"> <!--attempt to set BindingContext to MainPage.xaml.cs-->
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TestHeight}"/> <!--This XAML is in MainPage.xaml, this "TestHeight" variable is in MainPage.xaml.cs-->
    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>


Instead of binding to self, you may bind to the Grid's ancestor which is the MainPage. For more info, you may refer to Relative bindings.

You set BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, that means you set the BindingContext to the Grid itself and the Grid doesn't have mainpage Property. That's the reason why it doesn't work.
As a solution, you may either use Relative binding or x:reference
If you want to use Relative Binding, try the following way to set the BindingContext of the Grid (not RowDefinition) to MainPage,
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTest">


<Grid BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPage}}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--attempt to set BindingContext to MainPage.xaml.cs-->
        ...
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TestHeight}"/>

If you want to use x:Reference, remember to set the x:Name for the MainPage, and use x:Reference Binding expression.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         x:Name="mainpage"
         >

<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <!--attempt to set BindingContext to MainPage.xaml.cs-->
       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       ...
       <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TestHeight,Source={x:Reference mainpage}}"/>

Both of the above ways work. Please let me know if you have any question.
